# Hp deskjet f4280 paper jam without a paper E error

Tags: printing, printer

It was working fine and some how it just stop working... the flashing lights are, Ink lights(Orange), Paper Adjust(Green), Resume(Orange), it has new ink, I have open it and clean the headers., I have also try to reset it but no luck... there is nothing stock in there yet it shows on my windows that there is a paper jam, there is no paper jam or paper at all... when I open it I didn't disassemble it complete just the top scanner and the base controllers to have access to the rail... and yes the area where the ink is sitting was full of ink but I clean it very well, then I put it all together but the error is the same... I don't know what else to do... 
Could it be the sensor that went bad?